# Disable networking only inside of a single terminal

Tags: networking, process, osx, firewall

I want to run a command in the terminal to disable networking, just in that terminal.  How can that be accomplished?  I'm running OSX.

Note: I only want to disable the networking in that terminal.  Everywhere else it should still function.  So if I open a second terminal, I should be able to ping Google.

Comment: What type of Linux are you using?

Comment: I'm running OSX

Comment: @ademartini please add that kind of useful and necessary information to your question, not as a comment.

Comment: @ademartini, I don't think that you can disable Networking in one terminal and allow it to run in another terminal, there's a reason why they call this a "command line"...

Comment: On Linux you can do this with [unshare](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/unshare.1.html), but I don't know if there's an equivalent on Mac OS X.